# Tag Video by Frame with GPS Info using GStreamer

Tags: linux, video, gstreamer

I have been tasked to tag a video frame-by-frame with gps coordinates as it is recording. 
The platform must be on Linux (Ubuntu to be specific).

Very new to programming with video sources..

Some questions : 
Do video frames even have per-frame meta data?

Is GStreamer a good framework to use for my purposes? How should I get started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check GstMeta: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstMeta.html

It allows you to attach arbitrary metadata to buffers, which then can be passed downstream with the buffers and passed through other elements if possible. Take a look at the code of existing GstMeta implementations in gst-plugins-base for examples: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideometa.h http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideometa.c

Your meta would probably work very similar to the region of interest meta (plain metadata)

To get started, read the documentation on http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org , especially start with the application writers manual. And take a look at existing GStreamer code to understand how everything works together.